# Java TableLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, tablelayout, gridbaglayout

Im currently wanting to construct a table type of layout for JPanels. I found out there is a TableLayout for Java but I don't how to import it. On the other hand i found out there is a GridBagLayOut which also can construct a table like layout.But it seems more complicated. Any advice.

Comment: This doesn't strike me as specific enough to remain an open SO question ... to answer your question, persevere with `GridBagLayout` - it's not too complicated once you grok it.

Comment: Well I did some research on how to construct a table in java. And i came across TableLayout and GridBagLayout. TableLayout seems the way to go, but i couldnt really get it to work.

Comment: What's your question? GridBagLayout should do the job perfectly as far as I understand.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) of using a TableLayout, ([Introduction to TableLayout](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/tablelayout-141489.html))

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import layout.TableLayout;

public class TestTableLayout {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example of TableLayout");
        frame.setSize(450, 450);

        double size[][] = {{10, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 10}, // Columns
            {10, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 10}}; // Rows

        frame.setLayout(new TableLayout(size));


        String label[] = {"(1,1)", "(1,5)", "(1,3)", "(5,3)", "(3,3)"};
        JButton button[] = new JButton[label.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {
            button[i] = new JButton(label[i]);
        }


        frame.add(button[0], "1, 1");
        frame.add(button[1], "1, 5");
        frame.add(button[2], "1, 3");
        frame.add(button[3], "5, 3");
        frame.add(button[4], "3, 3");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

---

The required jar for the TableLayout can be downloaded from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/tablelayout.jar)

---

Also have a look at : [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) ,In case.

---

In case you go for GridBagLayout, have a look at : [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for you time and effort. Really appreciate it. It helped me alot

Comment: Is it possible to customize alignment of objects in cells of this table layout (for example, center objects inside of cells)?