# Layout manager for a TimLine bar

Tags: java, swing, layout

I am trying to create a timeline widget, a horizontal bar.

```
class TimeBar extends JPanel {
  public TimeBar(List<TimeRange> ranges) {
  ....
  }
}
```

The left edge represents the 00:00 and the right end  represents the 23:59.  I have to mark some pieces (time range) of this bar with different color. `List<TimeRange>` timeRanges (eg {10:34 - 12:49, RED}, {13:31 - 17:03, BLUE}). Doesn't exist overlap among the timeRanges.

The bar should be extendable (when the mainFrame changes size) but it should have min size 700 x 25. The TimeRangePanel should be clickable.

I have implemented using setLayout(null) for the TimeBarPanel and  setSize and setLocation for the TimeRangePanel. I recalculatino the sizes and the locations of the TimeBarPanel when the TimeBarPanel changes size. But it's not very good practice to setLocation manually instread of using a LayoutManager for it.

```
public class TimeRange { 
   Date startTime,
   Date endTime,
   Color color
} 

public class TimeBar extends JPanel
{
    private List<TimeRange> ranges;

    public TimeBar( List<TimeRange> ranges) {
    this.ranges = ranges;
        setLayout( null );
        setBackground( Color.GRAY );
        setMinimumSize( new Dimension( 720, 25 ) );

       for(TimeRange range : ranges  ) {
           int startX = calculateStartPoint(range);
           int widthX = calculateWidth(range)
           TimeRangePanel panel =  new TimeRangePanel(startX, widthX, range.color)
           add(panel);   
       }
    }
}

public class TimeRangePanel extends JPanel 
{
     public TimeRangePanel(int startX, int widthX, Color color) {
    setBackground(color);
    setSize(widthX, HEIGHT);
        setLocation(startX, 0 );
        setBounds(new Rectangle(new Point(startX, 1), getPreferredSize())); 
     }
}
```

Which is the best layout manager to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is going to depend on what you put on the timeline.  If it is fixed periods (hour, half-hour, etc.) then a `GridLayout` would be the simplest option.

If you are going to have overlap of multiple items, then a `TableLayout` or a `GridBagLayout` are good options.

Almost any situation is going to be better off with some type of layout manager than not using one at all.  However, if you really need something fancy and don't need components on the timeline, you could just look at creating a custom component that overrides `paintComponent` to drawl the timeline with highlighted ranges.

Tutorials or links for more about suggested layouts:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html
[Java TableLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476832/java-tablelayout)

Comment: In the case of the GridBagLayout, may you write me how the GridBagConstrants look like. I have calculated the width and the start point of each TimeRangePanel.

Comment: I updated my answer with some links.  It sounds like you are asking a new question about how to use GridBagLayout.